# How to store constantly coordinates in a DB, and then update/replace on changes?

Tags: sql, database, gps, coordinates

I want to store **GPS coordinates** from any device into a DB on a SQL SERVER, and check it in real time on a web, that will ask constantly for positions.

I saw others questions and answers (on StackOverflow and Google), and everybody want to add new rows (with the coordinates) on a table, where there were already stored previous coordinates.

In my case, I don't want to store previous coordinates, I just want to know where are they **NOW**, so I think it has no point to add new rows.
Therefore, the numbers of rows will remain constant.

Since I had two tables: *DEVICES(idDevice, device)* and *COORDINATES(device, long, lat)*, **everytime** a device send a new position (let's say every 1 second), it value will UPDATE the row existing with its previous value.

My question: Is that the best way (the "continuously auto-replacement" technique) I can do that? or is there a more optimal way to update positions?

And, like a 2nd question: that's the best way to build the tables for what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are definitely storing only one set of coordinates then I would suggest you remove `COORDINATES` and use `DEVICES(idDevice, device, long, lat)`.  You must already be handling making sure that a DEVICES row exists so now you can simply `UPDATE DEVICES SET long = xxx, lat = yyy WHERE idDevice = deviceId`.

Comment: Interesting approach. This denormalizes the table architecture but avoids the join, so the outcome will probably be faster response time. Wondering aloud here, would enabling RCSI and switching to optimistic locking allow for even faster response time (after properly reconfiguring Tempdb, of course)?